# How can i set up autoplay, loop and multiple songs after one is finished?

Tags: html, loops, iframe, playlist, autoplay

Thats what ive done so far

```
<div>
    <iframe src="/music/song1.mp3" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" width="1400" height="900" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<audio>` html element and add `autoplay loop`

```html
<audio autoplay loop controls>
  <source src="/music/song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

[See more about `<audio>` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)